# ContentResolver.delete deletes all entries from my ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-contentresolver

I have created an app in which I use a ContentProvider I created to keep track of some photos my app creates.

The concept is simple.
I capture some Images and save the Image name, date, and path to a ContentProvider.
And then I use this content provider to load each time thumbnails etc from this ContentProvider when my app starts etc.
I use a CursorAdapter and ListActivity for the full picture.

If the user deletes the image from a file manager or through my app, I want to delete that entry from the ContentProvider.

I have this method which is supposed to do so.

```
   private void deletePhotoFromContentProvider(String path){
        String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{path};
        Log.i(TAG, "Path to delete:" + path);
        String whereClause=""+PhotosContract.PHOTO_FILE_PATH+"=?";

        int res = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(PhotosContract.CONTENT_URI,
            whereClause, selectionArgs);
        Log.i(TAG, "Deleted :" + Integer.toString(res));
        mContext.getContentResolver().notifyChange(PhotosContract.CONTENT_URI,     null);
    }
```

My table has an ID, a photo_name, photo_date, photo_file_path.
I perform the delete based on the file_path which is basically unique.
I checked the path and the Log prints the correct one, but when i try to delete this deletes all my entries. Note that the

```
ContentValues values = initValues();
mContext.getContentResolver().insert(PhotosContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

works properly.

This is also my PhotosContract class

```
public class PhotosContract {

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.android.testapp.provider";
    public static final Uri BASE_URI = Uri
        .parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/");

    public static final String PHOTOS_TABLE_NAME = "photos";

    // The URI for this table.
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_URI,
        PHOTOS_TABLE_NAME);

    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String PHOTO_FILE_PATH = "photo_file_path";
    public static final String PHOTO_FILE_NAME = "photo_name";
    public static final String PHOTO_DATE = "photo_date";
}
```

I also tried to use something like this:

```
String whereClause=""+PhotosContract.PHOTO_FILE_PATH+"=" + path;

int res = mContext.getContentResolver().delete(PhotosContract.CONTENT_URI,
            whereClause, null);
```

but does not work either. It also deletes all my ContentProvider entries.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I am posting my delete method from my ContentProvider:

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
    int rowsDeleted = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(
            PhotosContract.PHOTOS_TABLE_NAME, arg1, arg2);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(
            PhotosContract.CONTENT_URI, null);
    return rowsDeleted;
}
```

Comment: Show the code for your implementation of `ContentProvider`. Are you actually passing the `selection` and `selectionArgs` arguments from the `ContentProvder.delete()` function into the `SQLiteDatabase.delete()` call?

Comment: Code added after the EDIT:. Seems weird though, I did try it on a physical device with an API level of 19 and it works. The emulator runs on level 18 API. This shouldn't happen though because I have declared a minimum API level of 18 in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Your `ContentProvider.delete()` function looks good to me. So I can't see why it isn't working properly. My advise is to run a test case again and check at every step. If the problem is there then double check everything in your code for bloopers. I bet that when you find your problem you will smack yourself in the head for being silly stupid.

Comment: BTW: A minSdkVersion of 18 allows to run apps with API 18 and up. So that your emulator on API 18 runs your app with minSdkVersion 18 is as it should be.